# How to use Delegate in C# for Dictionary<int, List<string>>

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, delegates, invoke

The code:

[1]

```
private delegate void ThreadStatusCallback(ReceiveMessageAction action, 
      Dictionary<int, List<string>> message);
```

[2]

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> messagesForNotification = 
      new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
```

[3]

```
Invoke(new ThreadStatusCallback(ReceivesMessagesStatus), 
     ReceiveMessageAction.Notification , messagesForNotification );
```

[4]

```
private void ReceivesMessagesStatus(ReceiveMessageAction action, object value)
{
    ...
}
```

How can I send the two variable of type `ReceiveMessageAction` respectively `Dictionary<int, List<string>>` to the `ReceivesMessagesStatus` method.

Thanks.

---

I have a function that is executed in a thread. Here I create an object of type `Dictionary <int, List <string>>` and using a delegation I whant to use this object in my form.

A part of the code is above:
[1] Decraration of the delegated
[2] The object
[3] The Call Of the delegate
[3] the function Where the object Need To Be send

Comment: Could you elaborate a little?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

[1]

```
Invoke(new ThreadStatusCallback(ReceivesMessagesStatus), new object[] { ReceiveMessageAction.Notification, messagesForNotification } );
```

[2]

```
private void ReceivesMessagesStatus(ReceiveMessageAction action, Dictionary<int, List<string>> value)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it type-safe without casting by using a lambda:

```
  Invoke(new MethodInvoker(
    () => ReceivesMessagesStatus(ReceiveMessageAction.Notification, messagesForNotification)
  ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried casting value as a Dictionary? e.g.

```
private void ReceiveMessagesStatus(ReceieveMessageAction action, object value)
{
    var myDictionary = (Dictionary<int, List<string>>)value;
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Emanuel: Why not be? Maybe `value as (Dictionary<int, List<string>>)` ?